ASP.NET - How to save pdf after filling it
I would like to show a pdf file in my form, filling it and save the result in pdf file.
To show the file, I use:
<asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />

Dim embed As String = "<object data=""{0}"" type=""application/pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""1200px"">"
embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = ""{0}"">here</a>"
embed += " or download <a target = ""_blank"" href = ""http://get.adobe.com/reader/"">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file."
embed += "</object>"
ltEmbed.Text = String.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/gaz.pdf"))

But, how to get the result and save it in pdf?

OK. I would have prefered to use my pdf files because it's more easy. Is there another solution, other than crystal report ? Finally, I want to upload file in a folder on my server
